# Not able to execute pip commands even though pip is installed and added to PATH

Tags: python, pip

I already have pip installed and added the corresponding path to my path,however I dont seem to be able to execute any pip commands(see below),what am I missing?

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip>get-pip.py
You are using pip version 6.0.6, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip>pip install subprocess32
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: try navigating out of the pip folder and running pip. sometimes starting with a fresh terminal window helps.

Comment: In order for `cmd` (or any process, really) to find `pip`, the directory where it is installed needs to be on your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `pip` installed but you don't have any command named `pip`.

try `python -m pip`

Comment: looks like usage is not right....it prints out the usage as below,which option should I use`Usage:
  C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip <command> [options]

Commands:
  install                     Install packages.
  download                    Download packages.
  uninstall                   Uninstall packages.
  freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements format.
  list                        List installed packages.

completion
  help                        Show help for commands.`

Comment: Try this then. "C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install #whatever#